# edx fullstack installation on a remote server using vagrant & virtualbox

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, remote-server, edx

and thank you for reading my question.

- I would like to install an edX platform on a remote server, using [the method explained here](https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edx-Full-stack--installation-using-Vagrant-Virtualbox) (with virtualbox and vagrant)
- To do so, I am connecting to the remote machine through ssh (port: 22).
- The remote server is running on CentOS 6.
- Virtual box 4.3.2 and vagrant 1.7.2 have been installed successfully on the remote machine, and the Vagrantfile has been retrieved. [You can find the vagrant file here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edx/configuration/master/vagrant/release/fullstack/Vagrantfile)

The problem arises when running **vagrant up**. 
The virtual machine is fetched and added but

```
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the 'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured properly and try again.
```

By looking around I found that it means that the CPU does not support VT-X technology. I tried a workaround changing the vagrant file to only use one cpu.

```
CPU_COUNT = 1
```

The procedure then gets further but there comes a second problem. I cannot connect through ssh to this virtual machine.

```
*==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...**
**    default: Adapter 1: nat**
**    default: Adapter 2: hostonly**
**==> default: Forwarding ports...**
**    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)**
**==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...**
**==> default: Booting VM...**
**==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...**
**    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222**
**    default: SSH username: vagrant**
**    default: SSH auth method: private key**
**    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...**
**    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...**
**    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...**
**    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...**
**    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...**
**    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...*
```

So multiple questions:

- If I cannot connect, it can mean that the machine hasn't booted up, so the problem can come from using only one CPU instead of two ?
- The problem might come from the port 2222 not being open. If so, why can't I connect to the machine directly through ssh on 192.168.33.10, as defined in the vagranfile ? Does vagrant need this initial ssh connection to actually set up the ip inside of the machine ?

I thought this would be the virtual machine's ip.

```
**config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"**
```

- How could I see what the problem is on the machine that I want to boot up, being in remote ? (can I have GUI for that virtual machine running on a remote server ?)

Note: When I am doing the fullstack installation on my machine and not on the remote, everything is working perfectly.

Comment: is the remote machine (the centos box) is physical or virtual?

Comment: the remote machine (centos 6) is physical

Comment: after vagrant fails, if you run `VBoxManage list vms runningvms` on the remote machine, do you get any running virtual machine back?

Comment: yes it is on. do I need administration privileges to up it properly ? can that be the problem ?

Comment: I believe VirtualBox must be installed as root (via `sudo` for example), but in order to use it, no root privilege is needed. Have you installed it as root?

Comment: virtualbox has been installed by the administrator

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same issue.

**Option 1**

I added v.gui = true as follows:
................................

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v, override|
v.gui=true
end
```

................................

Just after "vagrant up --provider=virtualbox". I can see the gui of VirtualBox for a second, but it closes at once.

**Option 2**

goto BIOS configuration --

Turn on  VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration